# Asp.NET core project fails with NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

One of my open source projects has just started failing to build with the errror, when previously it used to build successfully (if I trigger a build for a previously successful commit, I still get this error  )

`C:\projects\formfactory\FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example\FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example.csproj : error : NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.2.4, but with current settings, version 2.2.1 would be used instead. To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish. Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not during restore. For more information, see https://aka.ms/dotnet-runtime-patch-selection.`

Full build log here [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mcintyre321/formfactory/builds/28484716)

The csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example</PackageId>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>

    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FormFactory\FormFactory.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FormFactory.AspNetCore\FormFactory.AspNetCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="bower install" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.2.301" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

from https://github.com/mcintyre321/FormFactory/blob/master/FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example/FormFactory.AspNetCore.Example.csproj

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by changing my build server environment from VS2017 to VS2019

Answer (score 0):

Try removing explicit version from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package - the version should be determined by the SDK (implicit version), as you're also using `TargetLatestRuntimePatch` setting. Had similar issues caused when specifying explicit metapackage version version.

Also, you might want to consider swapping it to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` as it is recommended - less 3rd party dependencies. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've changed the build environment to VS2019 and it's fixed it. I think with a bit more time to look at it I would follow your suggestion. It's been a hellava mission nursing this project from MVC classic to Core over the years...